# What am I supposed to do with all these fish?

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

In *Brothers: A Tale of Two Sons*, you eventually come to a chapter where there is a waterfall leading into a pool full of fish. I'm stuck with what to do next. Moving the brothers around in the pool, they can sort of corral the fish, but they eventually just swim away. The action buttons (triggers) don't do anything specific with the fish either, the brothers just splash in the water as they do in other water areas. Am I missing something to do with the fish, or is there something else I need to do to continue on with the level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to do in the pool. To move forward, just go around either staircase behind the pool and at the top, near the bench, look for a another staircase leading away from the pool. this is where you should go to move ahead.

The specific part is in this video:

Answer (score -1):

Is there a cliff wall near by with roots on it? If so, climb it.